# What determines if a Pokémon can speak English?

Tags: pokemon

From what I understand, Pokémon can communicate through telepathy, right? But logically, shouldn't that mean it's only exclusive to psychic type Pokémon? Hoopa and Mewtwo talking through telepathy makes sense as they are psychic type, but what about Pokémon like Kyurem, Entei, Meowth, Lucario, and at least ten others that I can't remember right this instance? They definitely aren't psychic so how are they talking?

Is the rule for talking just "being able to learn a psychic type move"? Because Keldeo and Meowth can't learn any psychic type moves through only levelling up yet they're talking just fine. Do Technical Machine moves count?

Comment: First off, game and anime are 2 totally different universes with different sets of rules. 
And Meowth learned it in the anime by following a speech class (yea i know it's weird)

Comment: @Kevin Li - In respect to the last sentence of your question, what does 'TM' stand for?

Comment: @LogicDictates Technical Machine, it's an item that you can use to teach a pokemon certain abilities in the games.

Comment: @A.bakker - Thanks.

Comment: @A.bakker Then how come Kyurem and Keldeo can still speak english?

Comment: a: The Anime makes 0 sense, it never did but after Johto it took a nose dive. 
b: maybe because they are legendaries?

Answer (score 1):

Practice?

Bulbapedia's got [a whole section](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Talking_Pok%C3%A9mon#In_the_anime) on Anime Pokemon speaking English, and it seems the hard part is the actually Speaking bit, not the "What does this sound mean" bit.

So if a Pokemon's got the right vocal apparatus, they probably can speak, if they figure out how to control their lips and vocal c(h)ords and stuff the right way.